# How do I configure/enable gzip compression in my (cloudbees hosted) application responses?

Tags: cloudbees

I have JSF2 based application running in cloodbees (JavaEE web profile) and I realized its http responses doesn't use gzip compression. How do I configure the Run@cloud in a way to enable the gzip compression ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your app a gzip servlet filter
see http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/filters.html

You also can create a feature request for this on https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/forums/180582-rfe-and-ideas-run-cloud